# How to transfer a pdf and its metadata in folder from a collaboration site to a myteam site library?

Tags: metadata, pdf

We have tried transferring the pdfs multiple ways:

1. Using windows explorer - which works but the metadata is not
   preserved
2. Moving pdfs one by one - not efficient enough
3. Tried transferring by using content and structure - when I selected
   the folder I wanted to transfer it said move is not support for
   lists and folders.

I want to know if there is another way we can move pdf documents saved in a folder from a collaboration site to another site all at one without losing its metadata when transferred?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using SharePoint Designer, copy paste all files together?

1. Moving files in windows explorer won't preserve the metadata. I have transferred a lot of files before with SharePoint Designer, but you would need to check the preserve metadata part.
2. Moving files one by one isn't efficient, with SharePoint Designer you can move as many files as you want.
3. It doesn't have limitations to copy paste folders.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the answer? Maybe based on your own experience? What did you do, and why is it more efficient? Thanks!

Comment: 1- Moving files in windows explorer won't preserve the metadata. I have transferred a lot of files before with SharePoint Designer, but you would need to check the preserve metadata part.

2- Moving files one by one isn't efficient, with SharePoint Designer you can move as many files as you want.

3- It doesn't have limitations to copy paste folders.

Comment: Super! I took the liberty of pasting your comment in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you did! :)